# Unable to get package name in appium

Tags: android, apk, appium

I am using `Appium` for mobile app testing but when i choose `APK` file then i am not able to see package name,launch activity name in `appium` drop downs,please find below screen shot .Please any one provide solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had setup everything right then *the **issue** is with the **space in the apk path**. Make sure you don't have space in your apk path.*

Your path :
E:\Appium Tutorials\APK\Futurepay.apk

I suggest rename the folder to AppiumTutorials. Then path will be

E:\AppiumTutorials\APK\Futurepay.apk

That should help!

Comment: You are welcome @RajeshOm. Please accept my answer if your issue is resolved.